# Java Program Speed database connection

Tags: java, database, performance, derby

I've finished writing my first java program that accesses a database and allows me to remote onto machines.

This works ok when I run it from my own machine (which also hosts the database it connects to). However, if I use it on another machine and connect to the database the program hangs considerably while it does the database task.

I expected it to be a small wait, however sometimes it can take afew miniutes before it finish's the task at hand.

Heres one of the tasks that it hangs on.

```
    public void ChangeSite() throws Exception{

    ConnectionPoolS demo = new ConnectionPoolS();
    DataSource dataSource = demo.setUp();

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;



    String Site = (String)Sites.getSelectedItem();
    jProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    jProgressBar.setStringPainted(true);
    jProgressBar.setString("Searching...");
    int sRecordNo; 
     sRecordNo = 0;
String IpAddress = null, IpRange = null, Atvisionpw = null, Port = null, Practice = null, Surgery = null;
try { 


    conn = dataSource.getConnection();
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Practice = '"+Site+"' and BRANCH = 'N'");
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( );

    while (rs.next()) {
    sRecordNo = sRecordNo + 1;
    Surgery = rs.getString("SURGERY");
    Practice = rs.getString("PRACTICE");
    IpAddress = rs.getString("IPADDRESS");
    Port = rs.getString("PORT");
    Atvisionpw = rs.getString("ATVISIONPW");
    IpRange = rs.getString("IPRANGE");
}
    if (sRecordNo == 1){
    SiteIp.setText(IpAddress);
    Password.setText(Atvisionpw);
    PcIp.setText(IpRange);
    }
    else if (sRecordNo > 1){
       Multisite();
    }
    jProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
    jProgressBar.setString("");
stmt.close();
conn.close();
}
```

This is all on a derby database.

What I am doing wrong? I am missing something? Is there a way I can run some kind of performance check on this to find out what exactly is causing it to hang while running the database task, as this is all internal on an internal network I wouldn't expect to be waiting as much as I am!

Edit: With some help from Stefan (Thanks a bunch) ive found that that using the break points it seems hang after running the line

```
conn = dataSource.getConnection();
```

the next line after that is now

```
stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Practice = '"+Site+"' and BRANCH = 'N'");
```

but it only hangs after running the Connection line so would this mean the connection to the physical database is causing the hang?

Edit2: I have now setting a Connection Pool, however its still hanging when connecting, im at a bit of a loss now!, would a different engine provide better results?

Comment: How good is the network connection? Check out with `ping`.

Comment: is the size of the DB considerably different and indexes are lacking?  At what stage is it hanging?

Comment: What happens if you execute the SQL query manually, and how many records are there in this table? Also, you can try setting a breakpoint at the first line of your `ChangeSite` method to step over every line. You can then figure out where your performance issue is at.

Comment: PeterMmm Network connection is good pings come back at 0.299ms

user2310289 not quite sure i understand what you mean by the size of the "DB considerably different and indexes are lacking" (This could be the issue i dont know) Im also unsure at what part its hanging how would i check this?

@Stefan If i execute it from a remote machine it executes successfully in 0.029 seconds, there is around 180 records on last check in the database i will look into breakpoints its something ive not used before

Comment: @ChristopherLewis what IDE are you using? Generally, you can click on the column right before your line to hightlight it (usually red). This means that you have a stopping point in your code if you run it in Debug mode. Your application will wait for you to either step into, step over etc your code. Also see [Wikipedia: Breakpoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breakpoint).

Comment: @Stefan im using Netbeans 7.3.1, and i found the debugging and break points thanks for that, the hang seems to happen after  `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host ); ` which would mean its the connecting to the database thats causing the issue?

Comment: @ChristopherLewis It seems so. Maybe you should keep a connection at hand and alive to avoid latencies due to setting up a new db connection?

Comment: @Fildor That doesn't reduce the time needed to create the connection. I'd suggest connection pooling, see my answer.

Comment: @Stefan That's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

After some searching (and your conclusion that creating the connection itself is the performance hog), I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062905/jdbc-with-mysql-really-slow-dont-know-why). Connection pooling is way more performant than setting connections up yourself. It's also easier to work with, as you don't have to manage connections yourself. Just keep in mind that you close your connection after you're done, so it can be returned to the pool for future use.

Comment: Hm interesting i shall have a look now and come back with the results

Comment: I've finally worked out this connection pooling stuff and unfortunately this hasn't helped. a side by side comparison of both version's im still getting the same times when the change site routine is run :(

Comment: @ChristopherLewis is there any way to step into that `DriverManager.getConnection( host )` method?

Comment: Sorry showing my "Newbieness" not sure i understand the "Step Into" could you clarify?. Also the new hang point is now ` conn = dataSource.getConnection();` Which is the connection pooling thing, updating my question with the new code

Comment: @ChristopherLewis when you set a breakpoint at `conn = dataSource.getConnection();` , you have some options, like Step Over, Step Into and Step Out. If you run your application in Debug mode with your breakpoint and your application hits your breakpoint, hit 'Setp Into' so you can go into the method 'getConnection()' (if possible) and you can go a bit deeper into the code so you can see what's taking so long.

Comment: Found it, However it doesn't seem to do anything (Unless i'm missing something obvious) Step Into just hangs then displays the point at the next line, so im guessing its not inspectable :(

Comment: @ChristopherLewis I was afraid of that. Let's try a different angle: is the remote machine in your local network? What is the response time of that IP if you ping it? What is your local resource usage (and that of the remote server)?

Comment: It is local the Database is currently stored on My Machine, i have a Mac next to me that i test the database connection on (And my cross platform bits) Ping from the mac to the database machine good 64 bytes from 172.16.30.10: icmp_seq=0 ttl=128 time=0.299 ms. Resource wise the Mac is doing nothing but running the Programme (And net beans when i've been doing the break point stuff). The Database server is on a workstation, but the useage on that is low i'm running a few other tasks but nothing intense and there's no topping out

Comment: @ChristopherLewis That doesn't pinpoint anything.. I'm afraid I can't help you any further. I googled around though (using 'DataSource.GetConnection slow' and similar searches) and there are tons of options you can try. Good luck!

Comment: Well thanks for the help anyway, i shall go back to googling and see if i can move forward from here at least you've helped me to pinpoint the issue if nothing else!

Answer (score 0):

use of **PreparedStatement** over **statement** may improve performance up to little bit.
some details about PreparedStatement

**PreparedStatement** is a class in java.sql package and allows Java programmer to execute SQL queries by using JDBC package. You can get PreparedStatement object by calling connection.prepareStatement() method.SQL queries passed to this method goes to Database for pre-compilation if JDBC driver supports it. If it doesn't than pre-compilation occurs when you execute prepared queries. Prepared Statement queries are pre-compiled on database and there access plan will be reused to execute further queries which allows them to execute much quicker than normal queries generated by Statement object.

How to use **PreparedStatement**

```
public class PreparedStmtExample {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException {
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn =     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DataBase","username","Password");
        PreparedStatement preStatement = conn.prepareStatement("select *  from tableName where Name=?");
        preStatement.setString(1, "test");

        ResultSet result = preStatement.executeQuery();

        while(result.next()){
            System.out.println("Loan Type: " + result.getString("loan_type"));
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: You keep contradicting yourself. First you say that pre-compilation occurs if the JDBC driver supports it, which isn't correct, then you seem to say that it happens unconditionally, which is also incorrect.

Comment: @EJP It would be nice if you go through murachs java jsp and servlet 2nd edition book

Comment: @javaBeginner I do not see why he should? It is the RDBMS that has to support prepared statements, not the driver. Do you refer to a concrete passage from that book? I am always willing to learn :)

Comment: @javaBeginner You must be kidding. I should read your book just to suit you? I'm really not interested in any reference you can produce unless it is either the JDBC Specification or vendor documentation.

Comment: Don't introduce contentious terms into the discussion. Nobody has said anything about lying other than you. Your request remains ridiculous. I don't propose to read a book recommended by you just so I can comment further on your question, and I don't know why you think all books are perfect. They aren't. The point is that you cannot cite a third party document as evidence: only the specifications I referred to above.

Comment: @EJP I agree wid you,So I am removing all comments,

Comment: On a side note this, more relating to my question this didn't help :(