# Improve performance on native sql query

Tags: postgresql, jakarta-ee, eclipselink, payara

I'm trying to build a location-based application in Java EE, which returns providers from a certain radius given coordinates as input. As I use JPA, I couldn't find a solution to querying the database with a named query as it doesn't support functions like Sin, Cos etc. I found a nice read here, [sql-haversine](http://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/haversine-mysql-nearest-loc/), where I could use a native query instead. The query executes fast (33 ms) on the database (Postgres), but very slow when executed from the application (> 800 ms).

Is there a way to speed things up, from the application end, or do you have to use something like a stored procedure in the database.

My method looks like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Company> findCompaniesByProximity(Coordinate coordinate, int distance) {
    double latitude = coordinate.getLatitude();
    double longitude = coordinate.getLongitude();
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM ("
            + "SELECT *, c.distance_unit * DEGREES(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(c.lat)) * COS(RADIANS(companies.latitude)) * "
            + "COS(RADIANS(c.lng) - RADIANS(companies.longitude)) + SIN(RADIANS(c.lat)) * SIN(RADIANS(companies.latitude)))"
            + ") AS distance "
            + "FROM Companies "
            + "JOIN (SELECT  ?1 AS lat, ?2 AS lng, ?3 AS search_radius, 111.045 AS distance_unit) "
            + "AS c ON 1=1 "
            + "WHERE companies.latitude "
            + "BETWEEN c.lat  - (c.search_radius / c.distance_unit) "
            + "AND c.lat  + (c.search_radius / c.distance_unit) "
            + "AND companies.longitude "
            + "BETWEEN c.lng - (c.search_radius / (c.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(c.lat)))) "
            + "AND c.lng + (c.search_radius / (c.distance_unit * COS(RADIANS(c.lat))))"
            + ") AS proximity "
            + "WHERE distance <= search_radius "
            + "ORDER BY distance "
            + "LIMIT 25";
    List<Company> companies = null;
    try {
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql, Company.class);
        query.setParameter(1, latitude);
        query.setParameter(2, longitude);
        query.setParameter(3, distance / 1000.0);
        companies = (List<Company>) query.getResultList();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.err.println("Argument is invalid " + e);
    } catch (PersistenceException e) {
        System.err.println("PersistenceException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return companies;
}
```

The method is called from a singleton EJB, and I'm using Payara server with Postgres and EclipseLink. Everything is called locally so I thought the connection to database would be much faster. Iv'e also tried the postgres earthdistance extension, but it was even slower ( > 1800 ms). I've quite new to programming and especially Java EE so I might have done something wrong along the way :)
Thanks, in advance.

Comment: I have worked with a query similar to yours before.  I found [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062905/jdbc-with-mysql-really-slow-dont-know-why) which suggests that the connection setup time in your JDBC layer is what is making everything so slow.  I would not expect the query execution time on Postgres itself to vary so much.

Comment: Ah ok, thank you. But I thought that, when you use an ejb with an Entitymanager to connect to the database, the connections are pooled, and not closed every time. Or is that wrong. Is there a way improve the connection setup time?

Comment: I know perhaps less than you about connection pooling, but you should check this as it could be the cause for the slow performance.  For instance, when you execute the same query twice, back-to-back, does the second Haversine query _also_ take > 800ms?  If the second one is much faster, then this would imply the time is being lost during setup.

Comment: No, I tried executing it several times in a row, it is still > 800 ms. But, I get my input coordinate from a html-form so I have to reload the page, don't know if that impacts the back-to-back.

Comment: This is not what I mean.  I mean if, in your _Java_ code, you execute the query twice, how long does each take?  I suspect the second will be faster because there is no setup time.  I don't mean execute the same thing over and over, this will be the same.

Comment: Ah, you're right. The second query only takes 58 ms. Which I consider acceptable when it is sorting over 2000 providers in that area. But what can I do, to make the query that fast every time?

Comment: I am out of ideas at the moment, as I am better at writing queries than making Java write them.  I have upvoted you and I hope that a guru will help you.

Comment: Thank you, for taking the time anyway. Have a nice day.

Comment: What you've shown is not enough to go on, you need to profile the app to determine what is going on and where your time is being spent.  For instance, is the time spent within the method, or in the setup to this method?  How is your persistence unit deployed and the factory lifecycle managed?  How many results are returned - note that JPA has to turn your raw data into entities, which also adds some time, but that these entities are maintained in a cache.

Comment: Would you try to create a simple REST endpoint or servlet to call the method `findCompaniesByProximity`? It is necessary to isolate the call to the database from any other processing to see if the connection is really the tthing that is slowing down. I would guess that your application runs lot more queries during the transaction - that would slow the response time significantly. Try to run your native SQL query in isolation to see if the execution time is better.

Comment: The method findCompaniesByProximity is called from within a servlet. The servlet only extracts the input parameters from the html-form and passes them to the method. I have noticed that when called in an area with less providers it returns fast ( < 20 ms) even if it returns the same amount of providers (i.e.) 25. So, maybe the additional time is due to calculations in the database. What I can't understand is, why executing the same query on postgres only takes approx. 30 ms to do the calculations in an area with 2000 providers when it takes more than 800 ms when executed from the metod.